# Select statement not working properly in SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm using the below code to create an sql data grid on a web page in an ASP.Net web application.

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        string strConnString = "server= N-1077; Trusted_Connection=yes; database=Slaughter; connection timeout=30";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT WeekEndingDate = CONVERT(date, Week_Ending_Date, 103), Week_Number, North_Island, South_Island FROM Slaughter ORDER BY WeekEndingDate DESC"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why but when I call the select statement - "SELECT WeekEndingDate = CONVERT(date, Week_Ending_Date, 103), Week_Number, North_Island, South_Island FROM Slaughter ORDER BY WeekEndingDate DESC" - the WeekEndingDate still shows up on the web page with the datetime.

[image]

If I run the same command in Sql Server it does it correctly.

[image]

So what am I doing wrong here? Here is the html side of things just in case that is the problem.

```
<div style="width: 1250px; height: 300px; overflow: auto">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#6699ff" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" RowStyle-BackColor="#ccffff" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" 
        AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="false" AllowPaging="false" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="WeekEndingDate" HeaderText="Week Ending Date" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="Week_Number" HeaderText="Week Number" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="North_Island" HeaderText="North Island" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField ="South_Island" HeaderText="South Island" ItemStyle-Width="150px" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `103` from convert that is not needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will format date:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField ="WeekEndingDate" HeaderText="Week Ending Date" ItemStyle-Width="150px" dataformatstring="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}"/>
```

Comment: So close but I'm getting the date format like this 00-09-2015     and all days are 00?

Comment: Because ASP.Net has a datetime datatype. That's means every date has a time. Since the query returns 0 time, that's why it's being displayed as 12:00:00 AM when it is being bound as you get the full date + time when it displays it. You have to format the data from there as Pankaj Kapare has illustrated with the dataformatstring

Comment: Corrected date format. It should work as expected now.

Comment: As a matter of interest why the difference between mm and MM?

Comment: The small “m” and “mm” gives you the minute without and with a leading zero respectively.
The capital “M” and “MM” gives you the month without and with a leading zero respectively.

Answer (score 1):

`CONVERT(date, Week_Ending_Date, 103)` converts the value of Week_Ending_Date to a date datatype in the returned dataset. .NET receives that as a DateTime and the default string format of a DateTime includes the time value. That's why your web page has the time displayed. If you do not want the time displayed, convert the value to a string either in your SQL: `CONVERT(nvarchar(10), Week_Ending_Date, 103)` or in your ASP tag: `dateformatstring="{0:d}"` or `dateformatstring="{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"` if your current culture settings don't give you the format you want with the first one.